# Signo de puntuación antes de "para que"

Tags: puntuación

Encontré esta frase:

> Pues para eso exhibieron el cuadro: para que todos lo vieran.

¿Es normal poner dos puntos antes de *para que* en una oración final?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El [DPHD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=%3A) parece avalarlo:

> **DOS PUNTOS**. Signo de puntuación (:) que representa una pausa mayor que la de la coma y menor que la del punto. Detienen el discurso para llamar la atención sobre lo que sigue, que siempre está en estrecha relación con el texto precedente. Se escriben pegados a la palabra o el signo que los antecede, y separados por un espacio de la palabra o el signo que los sigue.
>
> **1.8.** Se usan también para conectar oraciones relacionadas entre sí sin necesidad de emplear otro nexo. Son varias las relaciones que pueden expresar:
> a) Causa-efecto: Se ha quedado sin trabajo: no podrá ir de vacaciones este verano.
> b) Conclusión, consecuencia o resumen de la oración anterior: El arbitraje fue injusto y se cometieron demasiados errores: al final se perdió el partido. En este caso se usa también el punto y coma (→ punto y coma, 3b).
> c) Verificación o explicación de la oración anterior, que suele tener un sentido más general: La paella es un plato muy completo y nutritivo: tiene la fécula del arroz, las proteínas de sus carnes y pescados, y la fibra de sus verduras. En este caso se usa también el punto y coma

Answer (score 3):

Fíjate en que realmente es una aposición de "para eso". Yo estoy muy a favor de los dos puntos en tu ejemplo.